# Apache Tika - Data file mime type is shown as text/plain

Tags: apache-tika

I am new to Apache Tika . I am using tika to get the file mime type. Below is the code I use

```
    TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = config.getDetector();
    MediaType mediaType = null;
    try{
        try(TikaInputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(file)) {

            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            metadata.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
            mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
        } 
    }catch (IOException e) {

    } 
    System.out.println("Mime Type ="+mediaType.toString())
```

Unfortunately the mime type for a .dat file is being shown as 'text/plain', instead of "application/octet-stream". Any help to fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: If you open your test file in a text editor, does it show as binary nonsense, or is it in fact text based?

Comment: @ Gagravarr the test file is text based... not a binary one

Comment: Sounds like Apache Tika is giving you the right answer then! `application/octet-stream` is the answer for unknown binary type files, which your file doesn't sound to be

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for the response..so data file can have mime types application/octet-stream or text/plain based on the content?

Comment: A given file could have one of about 1500 different mime types, as that's what Apache Tika currently supports!